# SQLite in Xamarin throws exception in connection

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have a problem. I am using Xamarin for iOS and Android applications. But it always throws an exception when I try to build a connection to the folder path. This is my code:
    public class Queries
    {
        private string folder = DependencyService.Get().GetAppDataFolder();

```
    public bool createDataBase()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(Path.Combine(folder, "Test.db")))
            {
                connection.CreateTable<Posten>();
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SQLiteEx", ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

It throws the exception in the using. I use the DependencyService to get the path I want to put my database in.

```
private string folder = DependencyService.Get<IFileSystemService>().GetAppDataFolder();
```

on the android side (i'm currently just testing android) i have implemented it like this:

```
public class FileSystemServiceAndroid : IFileSystemService
{
    public string GetAppDataFolder()
    {
        return System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    }
}
```

this is what the exception says:

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for >'SQLite.SQLiteConnection' threw an exception. occurred

I just moved the code where I try to access the createDataBase method to where my toolbar is initialized and I got a message box in the application:
[image: The Error]

Comment: what say the exception?

Comment: When is the exception occurred? During build or runtime?

Comment: Just during runtime when I deploy it on my device

Comment: Could you provide more detail of the exception from the debug output?

Comment: which sqlite package do you use?

Comment: I use the sqlite-net-pcl by Frank A. Krueger for more details i'll update my question soon. thanks guys

Comment: I put some lines from the output in there i don't know how much you need, sorry

Comment: I just moved the calling of the method a little bit and got this message box telling me i don't have all packages. But I do have all packages I suppose

Comment: You have the packages installed in both your PCL and your Android project?

Answer (score 0):

In my project with SQLite.PCL in Xamarin.Android, I am using the following to get the database folder and file location:

```
String dbFolder = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + "/project_name/";
String dbFileName = "project_name.db";
String dbPath = dbFolder + dbFileName;
//To check if the database file exists: System.IO.File.Exists(dbPath);
//To delete the database file: System.IO.File.Delete(dbPath);
SQLiteConnection dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
```